# Changing color and marker of dataset using seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

I want to add an additional variable to the plot listed below. At the moment I have a different colour of marker corresponding to a different metal. But for every metal, there is a different geometry, so I would like to add a marker for every colour (e.g. red dot and red square). When I add "style=POM" I get this error message:

ValueError: Could not interpret value `POM` for parameter `style`

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Example .csv file:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfdata=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/2586376t/conda/BOTH.csv')

sns.jointplot(data=dfdata, x="MO", y="ORB", hue="METAL")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please share [the data as text and not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)?

Answer (score 0):

`style=POM` tries to set the parameter `style` to `POM`. In seaborn jointplot, the `style` parameter does not exist 
Ref : https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html

If you want 1 plot with different colors corresponding to different metals and different markers corresponding to different `POM` values then your solution is to use a scatterplot like this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfdata=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/2586376t/conda/BOTH.csv')

plot = sns.scatterplot(data=dfdata, x="MO", y="ORB", hue="METAL" , style=dfdata['POM'])

plt.show()
```